# Consulta em 3 tabelas e comparações com sql

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite!
Estou com um impasse aqui.
Estou pensando na melhor maneira de resolver uma solução.
O problema é o seguinte:
Eu possuo 3 tabelas com os nomes de Monstros, itens e inventário.
O Monstro possui um inventário, neste inventário possui 48 espaços.
Cada espaço pode ou não estar preenchido com um item.
Qual seria a forma correta de se fazer consultas nessas tabelas?
Por exemplo se o usuário buscar por monstro ele deve exibir todos os itens dentro deste inventário e se o usuário buscar por itens ele deve exibir todos os monstros que possuem este item no inventário.
Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo prático de como fazer isso somente usando sql?
Grato desde já.

Comment: Acho que começa por arrumar a tabela inventário e por um ítem por linha, e nao 48 numa linha só. A não ser que você tenha uma razão muito especial para isso (apesar da probabilidade ser baixa). A tabela "inventario" poderia ser id, id_dono, id_item, assim você pesquisa por item ou por dono. Só que eu acho que você poderia elaborar melhor a questão.

Comment: é que o inventário do monstro contem 48 espaços,  cada espaço pode ou não conter algum item.

Comment: essa solução que eu disse permite quantos espaços vc quiser, podem continuar sendo 48. Só que ficariam 48 entradas separadas, muito mais facil de remover um item ou acrescentar, e pra fazer as buscas tudo fica simples. Se eles tiverem posições certas, basta mais um campo numérico "posicao".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve respeitar as regras normais de banco de dados.

```
Primeira Forma Normal (ou 1FN) requer que todos os valores de colunas em uma tabela sejam atômicos (exemplo: um número é um átomo, enquanto uma lista ou um conjunto não o são). A normalização para a primeira forma normal elimina grupos repetidos, pondo-os cada um em uma tabela separada, conectando-os com uma chave primária ou estrangeira;
Segunda Forma Normal (ou 2FN) requer que não haja dependência funcional não-trivial de um atributo que não seja a chave, em parte da chave candidata;
Terceira Forma Normal (ou 3FN) requer não haver dependências funcionais não-triviais de atributos que não sejam chave, em qualquer coisa exceto um superconjunto de uma chave candidata;
Forma Normal de Boyce-Codd (ou BCNF) requer que não exista nenhuma dependência funcional não-trivial de atributos em algo mais do que um superconjunto de uma chave candidata. Neste estágio, todos os atributos são dependentes de uma chave, de uma chave inteira e de nada mais que uma chave (excluindo dependências triviais, como A → A);
Quarta Forma Normal (ou 4FN) requer que não exista nenhuma dependência multi-valorada não-trivial de conjuntos de atributo em algo mais de que um superconjunto de uma chave candidata;
Quinta Forma Normal (ou 5FN ou PJ/NF) requer que não exista dependências de joins (associações) não triviais que não venham de restrições chave;
Domain-Key Normal Form (ou DK/NF) requer que todas as restrições sigam os domínios e restrições chave.
```

Tendo isso em mente, sabemos que não existem atributos multivalorados, por exemplo em 1 linha e 1 coluna varias informações na mesma coluna.
Também sabemos que um banco de dados ele é escalavel verticalmente e não horizontalmente, logo é preferivel que seu banco cresça pra baixo e não para os lados.

Ai podemos chegar na estrutura +- assim:

Monstro: ID, NOME, etc etc

Inventário: ID,Id_Monstro, especificações, slots, etc etc

Itens: ID, Nome, atributos, etc etc

Agora como fazer para unir?

Vamos ver, 1 inventario pode ter 0 ou mais itens
1 item pode ter 1 inventario
1 monstro pode ter 1 inventario

Com isso chegamos a conclusão que precisamos de uma tabela associativa.
Fica assim:
ItensInventario
Id_Inventario, Id_Item, Quantidade? etc

Conclusão,

quando temos um relacionamento de 1 para 1 como por exemplo monstro e inventario podemos associa-los diretamente na tabela.
mas quando a associação é 1 pra muitos ou muitos pra muitos, é necessario uma tabela associativa.
Seu select ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_monstro
INNER JOIN tabela_inventario ON tabela_monstro.id = tabela_inventario.id_monstro
INNER JOIN tabela_associativa_inventario ON tabela_inventario.id = tabela_associativa_inventario.ID_inventario
LEFT JOIN tabela_itens ON tabela_associativa_inventario.id_item = tabela_itens.ID
```

Pronto.

Edit. Se vc quer uma quantidade fixa de slots como 48, você pode tratar isso no código, ou com alguma trigger ou algo do genero. Mas não é seguro assumir que esse valor é imutavel.

Edit2. Fonte das formas normais https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados