# Como somar os números de uma coluna no banco que tenha o mesmo id e que se repete?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: Eu troquei os nomes das variáveis para não dar plágio no meu trabalho]

Tenho uma tabela chamada `venda_itens` que tem `venda_id`, `item_id` e `item_quantidade`.

Queria trazer de volta o *nome do item* com a *quantidade total de itens* vendidos, e a *quantidade de itens totais*, através de um `inner join` com a tabela `item` que possui: o `nome` e a `quantidade_total`.

```
SELECT *FROM itens_venda inner join itens on itens.itens_id=itens.itens_id
```

Mas eu não sei como somar a quantidade vendida de itens na tabela `venda_itens`.
Como fazer?

Comment: Você está ciente que essa modelagem não está normalizada, certo?

Comment: Acho que essa explicação pode ser boa para entender sobre formas normais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103894/64969

Comment: Não entendi a nova modelagem. Tem como por um exemplo com algumas tuplas?

Comment: Atualizei com o print...

Comment: `produto` e `item` são a mesma coisa ? As tabelas `venda_itens`, `itens_venda` e `produto_venda` são a mesma coisa ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumindo que seu modelo e seus dados sejam algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE produto_venda
(
    venda_id INTEGER,
    prod_id INTEGER,
    prod_unidade INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE produto
(
    prod_id INTEGER,
    prod_nome TEXT,
    prod_valor_compra NUMERIC,
    prod_valor_venda NUMERIC,
    prod_unidades INTEGER,
    forn_id INTEGER
);

-- CADASTRO DOS PRODUTOS
INSERT INTO produto ( prod_id, prod_nome, prod_valor_compra, prod_valor_venda, prod_unidades, forn_id )
VALUES ( 10, 'Panela de Barro', 20.95, 40.25, 22, 15 );
INSERT INTO produto ( prod_id, prod_nome, prod_valor_compra, prod_valor_venda, prod_unidades, forn_id )
VALUES ( 20, 'Colher de Pau', 2.50, 4.20, 100, 15 );
INSERT INTO produto ( prod_id, prod_nome, prod_valor_compra, prod_valor_venda, prod_unidades, forn_id )
VALUES ( 30, 'Chaleira', 30.00, 50.50, 13, 15 );


-- VENDAS DE PANELAS DE BARRO
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 100, 10, 1 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 101, 10, 2 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 102, 10, 1 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 103, 10, 1 );

-- VENDAS DE COLHERES DE PAU
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 104, 20, 4 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 105, 20, 4 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 106, 20, 2 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 107, 20, 1 );

-- VENDAS DE CHALEIRAS
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 108, 30, 1 );
INSERT INTO produto_venda ( venda_id, prod_id, prod_unidade ) VALUES ( 109, 30, 1 );
```

Você pode usar a função de agregação `sum()` combinado com a cláusula `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    pv.prod_id AS id,
    p.prod_nome AS nome,
    p.prod_valor_venda AS valor,
    sum(pv.prod_unidade) AS qts_vendidos,
    sum(p.prod_valor_venda * pv.prod_unidade) AS total_vendido
FROM
    produto_venda AS pv
JOIN
    produto AS p ON ( p.prod_id = pv.prod_id )
GROUP BY
    pv.prod_id,
    p.prod_nome,
    p.prod_valor_venda
ORDER BY
    p.prod_nome;
```

Saída:

```
| id |            nome | valor | qts_vendidos | total_vendido |
|----|-----------------|-------|--------------|---------------|
| 30 |        Chaleira |  50.5 |            2 |           101 |
| 20 |   Colher de Pau |   4.2 |           11 |          46.2 |
| 10 | Panela de Barro | 40.25 |            5 |        201.25 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9d0a/1)

Comment: @Victorprvt: Edite a sua pergunta colocando mais detalhes sobre a estrutura das suas tabelas e sobre os dados contidos nelas, isso ajuda muito. Altero minha resposta assim que você o fizer.

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso! obg

Comment: Atualizado.....

Comment: @Victorprvt: Pronto! Ah!, E da próxima vez, tente elaborar uma pergunta mais detalhada, com mais informações e evite editá-la a ponto de descaracterizar a pergunta original. Todos Agradecem!

Comment: Desculpas, kara... é pq eu estou aprendendo.. mais agora eu vou sim! Obrigado, vc salvou minha vida! valeu mesmo!

Comment: @Victorprvt: Todos nós somos aprendizes por aqui, afinal, aprender é uma das maiores "sacadas" do SOpt. `;o)`